# redshift drop or truncate table very very slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

When drop or truncate a not too big table(4M rows) in my redshift database, it take very very long(hours) to complete.  Does anybody experience the same issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give some other information, such as table width, cluster setup, etc?

Comment: You should accept Gerardo's answer if it resolved your problem.

Answer (score 86):

Redshift has very fast I/O, so that opeation should take less than 1 second for any cluster type or size.
As diemacht said, the issue is caused because you have another connection with an open transaction.

I had a similar issue: A crash on the client left a transaction 'open' but unreacheable.
No db locks appeared on the STV_LOCKS table: (using `select table_id, last_update, lock_owner, lock_owner_pid from stv_locks;`)

Also, no query was still running: (checked with: `select pid, trim(user_name), starttime, query , substring(query,1,20), status from stv_recents where status='Running';`)

So the solution was to list the user sessions: `SELECT * FROM STV_SESSIONS` 
And then kill it using: `SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)`

Or the KILL'EM ALL version:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(process) FROM STV_SESSIONS where user_name='user_name' and process != pg_backend_pid();
```

Note that `CANCEL {pid}` did not work! (the query was cancelled but the transaction was still open and locking).

Comment: `SELECT pg_terminate_backend(process) FROM STV_SESSIONS where user_name='user_name' and process != pg_backend_pid();` doesn't work now. It returns `INFO:  Function "pg_terminate_backend(integer)" not supported.` message.

Comment: @masashimiyazaki, `pg_terminate_backend` won't work when selecting from a Redshift table'.  There was another message that indicated the function is not available on Redshift tables.    

Take the list of pids and apply pg_terminate_backend() to each separately.  Perhaps that behavior changed since the parent post.

Comment: isn't it possible to just add a timeout for the user queries in the WLM?

Answer (score 43):

In my experience, as @Gerardo Grignoli says, locks don't show up in the `stv_locks` table, but they do show up in `pg_locks`. Depending on your environment it may not be acceptable to kill an arbitrary long-running session listed in `stv_sessions`. I find the `pg_locks` table to be very reliable for detecting this type of lock:

```
select * from pg_locks where relation = (select oid from pg_class where relname = 'the_table')
select pg_cancel_backend(pid)
```

Typically, the issue is an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock that's deadlocking the table. So, if many locks are listed, find and kill the `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` one.

Answer (score 22):

IMO AccessShareLock on tables also causes DDL commands to get stuck.

Run this query to figure out pids of AccessShareLock

```
select
  current_time,
  c.relname,
  l.database,
  l.transaction,
  l.pid,
  a.usename,
  l.mode,
  l.granted
from pg_locks l
join pg_catalog.pg_class c ON c.oid = l.relation
join pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity a ON a.procpid = l.pid
where l.pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

Kill the processes using `select pg_terminate_backend(<pid>);`

Ensure that all your read-only applications close and releases all connections and hence these locks!

Comment: It was the AccessShareLock for me that was causing the problem as well.

Answer (score 7):

I've experienced the same problem.
It turned out to be opened transaction ran from somewhere else.

For example, if you have 2 shells open with redshift shell, you will not be able to drop a table from the first shell, that participate in an open transaction in the second shell.

After I committed / rolled back in the second window, truncate worked perfectly.

Hope it helped.